# What is the time unit returned by dji.common.mission.waypoint.Builder.calculateTotalTime()

Tags: dji-sdk

Unfortunately, DJI SDK documentation only states:

> Calculate the total time of the waypoint list.

Is that in seconds? Seconds' fraction? Minutes?

The same applies to `Builder.calculateTotalDistance()`:

> Calculate the total distance of the waypoint list.

I couldn't deduce the right time (and distance) units since I got different values for the same set of waypoints in different map locations (!). For instance, the same equally spaced waypoints in middle-east Brazil is different when they're applied in north-west of Canada. The difference is ~15%. What's the reason?

My SDK version is 4.13.1 for Android (MSDK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've e-mailed them through dev@dji.com and they've answered that the distance is in meters and the time, in seconds.

About the different values for middle-east Brazil and the north-west of Canada, I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

About the geographical variations, 1 degree of longitude at the equator is much bigger (in meters) that 1 degree close to the north pole. Sounds right what you observed.